# Mutt, how to stop mutt from changing email names

Tags: mutt

I recently switched to Mutt. Being able to backing up emails sounds cool. I use `rsync` to do so but I have a big headache. I use `Maildir` format. Each time Mutt opens an email, it changes the file name of the email, e.g. it likes to add one ",S" to the end. Then weeks later when I back up my mails, `rsync` is driven crazy. I guess Mutt does so because of some concurrency issues but as a personal user I do not have to worry about this. I hope to tell Mutt to keep the names of email files permanently unchanged. Question: how?

Comment: This is not programming question as far as I can see. You could try superuser.com or some unix/linux related Steck Exchange site.

Answer (score 1):

the ,`S` is`maildir` flag for `seen` ("mark as read"). that's the way `maildirs` work, i can't tell whether you can run mutt in read-only mode as far as that is concerned.

usually, when working with `maildirs`, it's a better idea to use a `maildir-aware`synchronization like `mbsync`. it will know of those flags and synchronize more efficiently because it can rely on all involved utilities to be aware of the ways to handle `maildirs` (that is, don't change files in-place, how to set flags etc).